# Ubuntu 16.04 partition unmounted when trashing a large amount of files

Tags: linux, ubuntu, partitioning

I have a dual boot Ubuntu 16.04 / MacOS El Capitan and a shared partition in Mac default format (HFS+). My dual boot and partition sharing are working well and I can access it from both sides.

When I'm on Ubuntu and working on this shared partition (HFS+), trashed files are transfered in Ubuntu trash folder and the system is lost:

- I can see files in the trash folder but cannot delete or restore them.
- When I delete huge amounts of data (I'm working with thousands of pictures), the partition is automatically unmounted from my Ubuntu system during delete process. To access it, I need to do a manual mounting after restart or switch to MacOS and come back.

I tried:

- deleting files from the command line
- Empty/restore the trash from the display
- Kill the trash process in running processes

Does anyone have an idea of what is causing the problem and what I can do to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, HFS+ is a non-native filesystem from a Linux perspective, so some amount of oddity with it is expected. That said, completely unmounting the filesystem when deleting files goes beyond the sort of quirks I'd expect, but it could be that this is at least part of what's going on. If so, and if none of the below suggestions help, switching to FAT may do the trick. Although FAT is also non-native, its drivers (in both Linux and macOS) are mature enough that it's unlikely to cause such problems. OTOH, FAT is also very limited compared to HFS+, so it may not be adequate (such as if you need to store large files).

In any event, a few specific issues may be at work here:

- **Journaling** -- By default, macOS creates HFS+ volumes with journaling active. In fact, this default cannot be disabled in recent versions of macOS when using the GUI Disk Utility. Journaling, however, is poorly supported in Linux's HFS+ drivers. Thus, for a shared data partition, it's best to disable journaling. Unfortunately, I don't know how to do this on an existing volume; but maybe a Web search will turn something up. If not, or if you don't mind doing a backup-reformat-restore juggle, you can do that. When you do, I'd suggest using `mkfs.hfsplus` in Linux to create the new filesystem. To create a non-journaled filesystem, you would *omit* the `-J` option. (Type `man mkfs.hfsplus` to learn more about this command.) If the command is not installed, you might need to install the `hfsprogs` package. There's a command-line way to do this in macOS, too; I believe the command is `newfs` or something similar. I don't recall the details, though.
- **Coordinated user IDs** -- By default, Ubuntu's first user ID (UID) is 1000, whereas it's 501 in macOS. Thus, when you try to share files on an HFS+ partition across these OSes, the files will appear to be owned by different users in each OS. Although it's possible to set permissions loosely or make heavy use of `sudo` to enable file-sharing to work, a better solution is to coordinate the UID values across the two installations. My answer to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/315078/how-to-manage-permissions-on-a-shared-volume-for-osx-and-ubuntu) on AskUbuntu describes how to do this in Ubuntu, and provides pointers to other sites that describe how to do it in macOS. (Making the change in macOS is preferable, but the process is more tedious in macOS.) In suggesting making this change, my hypothesis is that you may be running into permissions problems and that these problems are interacting with filesystem bugs that are causing the filesystem to be unmounted.
- **Filesystem errors** -- If the filesystem has been damaged, it may be causing the kernel to unmount it suddenly. You can run `fsck` on an HFS+ partition in Linux, and that should fix the problem, provided the `hfsprogs` package is installed. Apple open-sourced much of their HFS+ code, so in theory this should be pretty much identical to running a check in macOS; however, Apple's been making some changes to their filesystems lately, and I don't know if those changes have worked their way into Linux distributions' packages, so it may be safer to do the job from macOS, using Disk Utility. If Disk Utility gives you an option to do so, though, *do not* enable a journal on the partition, for the reasons noted earlier.

You may be able to gain some clues about what's causing the problem by looking at the kernel ring buffer immediately after the problem occurs. You can do this by typing `dmesg` to see the whole thing, or `dmesg | tail` to see the last few lines. (You can extend the number of lines shown via the `-n` option to `tail`, as in `dmesg | tail -n 20`; or you can use `less` rather than `tail` to be able to scroll through the whole thing.) The kernel ring buffer *should* record information on kernel failures, which an unrequested unmount of a filesystem is. OTOH, it's conceivable that whatever's causing the unmount isn't really a kernel failure, or the error reporting doesn't happen for some reason. If you try the above suggestions and they don't help, but if the kernel ring buffer shows something suspicious, you can try posting the details.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Rod Smith, about journaling and user ID, I initially took care of that by disabling journaling on macos and setting my Ubuntu user ID to 501 to access files. This config had been working for months without any problems that's why I was investigating on a bug but it was a nice reminder. I ran all debug commands you gave me but I didn't find anything concluding resolution. I finally decided to format this shared partition to /ext4 and I will grand access privileges to macos. Ubuntu is my main OS it should resolve future conflicts.